# Whereabout of the RSS4J project

Tags: java, rss, class-library

Anyone know what is the project home site of the RSS4J. I found several reference on Maven repositories, but can't find the original project site. Also is this project alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was on www.churchillobjects.com, but that domain has now been tranferred to a domain parking site.  The Wayback Machine has [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20070202202600/www.churchillobjects.com/c/13005.html) for RSS4J from February 2007.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [RSS4J](http://rss4j.sourceforge.net/) is hosted on SourceForge.

Answer (score 0):

in SourceForge, the project is empty. Thkz Mr Potato Head.